# GO - Docker ask certificate on K8S container

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, certificate, openid-connect

I use the following code with [this](https://github.com/coreos/go-oidc) lib

```
provider, err := oidc.NewProvider(ctx, providerURI)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

While running it locally **with same providerURI** it **works**,
I was able to get the provider successfully!

I deployed it to K8S with the **exact same provider url** (as `env` variable ) and **debug** it using `port-forwarding` ,
However, in k8S I got error and dont get the `provider`.

**The error is:**

```
2020/08/14 16:42:22 Get "https://ace.svar.com/.well-known/openid-configuration": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I've added the certificate to the image and **verify it**, I `exec` into k8s container after deploy and I see the `server.crt` file under `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` path.

And still got the same error, any idea if I miss here something else ...
Not sure if it really related to the OIDC lib or something more general..

```
FROM golang:1.14.7 AS builder
RUN go get github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
ADD server.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/server.crt
RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/server.crt && update-ca-certificates
RUN mkdir /app

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -gcflags="all=-N -l" -o main ./...

FROM debian:buster AS production
COPY --from=builder /app .
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/dlv /
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
EXPOSE 8000 40000
ENV SSL_CERT_DIR=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
ENV PORT=8000
CMD ["/dlv", "--listen=:40000", "--headless=true", "--api-version=2", "--accept-multiclient", "exec", "./main"]
```

I got replay from the author of the `GO-OIDC` repository to try to use

https://godoc.org/github.com/coreos/go-oidc#ClientContext

Not sure how, any idea?

Comment: It sounds like you have the CA for that host on your local machine so you can validate its certificate when you run it locally, but not on the container running on k8s.

Comment: @BurakSerdar - thanks, please see my update I've added certificate but not sure if this is the right place as I got the same error, how should I pass it to the provider or container ...

Comment: What you did is to add certificates to your server. You want to validate the remote server certificate from your client. If you can add certificates to the oidc library somehow, you can do that. Or, you have to mount the certificates to your container so they appear as one of the system CAs. Where you should mount them depends on your container base image.

Comment: @BurakSerdar - I've added my container, it will be great if you provide example how should I add the certificate to the container .

Comment: Your base image is debian. Find out where to add certificates to a debian system, and mount your certificates based on that.

Comment: @BurakSerdar - I've done it as you suggested, see my update to the post. and still got the same issue, any other idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [oidc.ClientContext](https://godoc.org/github.com/coreos/go-oidc#ClientContext) docs it shows how to pass in a custom `http.Client`:

```
myClient := &http.Client{}
ctx := oidc.ClientContext(parentContext, myClient)

// This will use the custom client
provider, err := oidc.NewProvider(ctx, "https://accounts.example.com")
```

providing a custom `http.Client` allows for custom TLS handling.

---

### TLS Config

To create a `http.Client` with a specific CA-trust file, I employ these helper functions:

```
func tlsConf(trustfile string) (t *tls.Config, err error) {
    if trustfile == "" {
        // DON'T USE IN PRODUCTION (but handy for testing)
        t = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
        return
    }

    pembody, err := ioutil.ReadFile(trustfile)
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("failed to load trust file %q: %w", trustfile, err)
        return
    }

    rootCAs := x509.NewCertPool()
    if ok := rootCAs.AppendCertsFromPEM(pembody); !ok {
        err = fmt.Errorf("invalid PEM file %q", trustfile)
        return

    }

    t = &tls.Config{RootCAs: rootCAs}
    return
}
```

and:

```
func httpCli(trustfile string) (hc *http.Client, err error) {
    tc, err := tlsConf(trustfile)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    hc = &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: tc}}
    return
}
```

So to use the above with the OIDC package for a quick test:

```
hc, err := httpCli("") // DON'T USE IN PRODUCTION - will trust any TLS cert

ctx := oidc.ClientContext(parentContext, hc)
provider, err := oidc.NewProvider(ctx, "https://accounts.example.com")
```

If this works, then add the correct trust file to your app:

```
hc, err := httpCli("/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/server.crt"))
```

---

### CA Trust

If your `server.crt` trust file is not working, you may have the wrong subject/issuer listed.

To know for sure, you can [grab the trust cert](https://superuser.com/a/176721/417258) (and optional signing chain) from any remote server (port 443 is the default https port):

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect ace.svar.com:443 -showcerts 2> /dev/null > ace.txt
```

Since I don't know what your infrastructure looks like, I'll use the example output from `google.com:443`:

```
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=*.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=GTS CA 1O1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIKIzCCCQugAwIBAgIQF9rkH7fB/M4IAAAAAE2d0TANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBC
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEeMBwGA1UEChMVR29vZ2xlIFRydXN0IFNlcnZpY2VzMRMw
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The `s:` indicates the subject of a cert - and you can see the server name is identified by the wildcard `CN=*.google.com`. If you see something similar within `ace.txt` - your `server.crt` should include these lines (starting at `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` and ending with `END CERTIFICATE`).

You may also note the `i:` line indicates the issuer cert name. If this is the same name as `s:` - then it is self-signed cert and you are done.

In the `google.com:443` example the subject (`s:`) differs from the issuer (`i:`). So instead of trusting the subject cert - one can trust the issuer cert instead - allowing potentially multiple servers to be trust. Since the subject cert is signed by that issuer - the chain-of-trust is complete.

Comment: Thanks, I want to try it, however I miss one thing `ctx := oidc.ClientContext(parentContext, hc)` what it the `parentContexts` , how could I achieve it, cloud you please add it to your answer ?

Comment: Thanks,1.  I use the parent contexts as `parentCtx := context.Background()` and use you code , is it OK? 2.  I've tried it by `not` passing the certificate and it works, however, when I configure that via path to the certificate `httpCli("/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/server.crt"))`  it doesnt work, I verify that that the file read succefully (dont get error in `tc, err := tlsConf(trustfile)` and get `tc` ,any idea why it doesnt work with certificate , this is company certificate which is public and widely used. any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: @bredstraruts - it sounds like your local system has your company trust file in the keychain. I've update the answer to show how you can extract the trust directly from the server itself.

Answer (score 3):

Golang standard ssl library is looking for certificates in the following directories: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/x509/root_unix.go#L18-L37 && https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/x509/root_linux.go#L8-L15, if you want to look it up in the new location, you can use environment variables: `SSL_CERT_FILE` or `SSL_CERT_DIR` and set location of your certificate.
So in your case it would be:

```
export SSL_CERT_DIR=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
```

and then run your application.

Comment: Thanks, Should I put in in the docker file / deployment .yml?

Comment: Since your are adding cert during docker image build, I would set this env variable in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Thank, I've added it to the docker file `ENV SSL_CERT_DIR=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` and got the same error :( , any other idea? I can share the certificate and the issuer if you would like to test it shortly in your end...

Comment: I've added to the docker in the post the env which you suggested to use

Comment: Can you try from within container `curl -vvv --cacert /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/server.crt https://ace.svar.com/` and see if there is no problems with the certificate?

Comment: HI, I was able to get response: like this  `Trying 157.133.170.71...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x562f302ebf50)
* Connected to ace.svar.com (157.133.170.71) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/server.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):`

Comment: Long response which ended with: `< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Tue, 18 Aug 2020 14:32:53 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Location: https://ace.svar.com/ui/protected/profilemanagement
< Content-Length: 263
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://ace.svar.com/ui/protected/profilemanagement">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host accounts.sap.com left intact`  any idea ?

Comment: Hmm weird, how does it work, you connect to `ace.svar.com` but connection is done to `accounts.sap.com`, in that case, I am surprised it is working on the host and it does not complain about invalid cert there. Do you have http proxy in your infra or something ?

Comment: There's most likely a wildcard cert being presented - or a wildcard cert installed in your system keychain. I suggest extract the remote servers cert (as I describe above) and investigate from there.